# Laravel is it good practice to extend base controller and extend it for rest of the controller and set common login in it?

Tags: php, laravel

Just to reduce the code duplication and easy implementation I have extended Laravel base `Controller` so can set middleware and some other stuff as I may add as I built. Finally this `AdminController` I am extending with the rest of all controllers that will be used under the Admin area. So I can inherit middleware and other stuff from the `AdminController`.

> **Question:** Is it a good practice to do so by extending the controller in Laravel?

### AdminController

```
class AdminController extends Controller
{
    use AdminMenu;

    public function __construct()
    {

        //auth user
        $this->middleware(['auth', 'admin']);

        //sidenav items
        $this->navItems();

    }

    ...

}
```

### UserController and Others

```
class UserController extends AdminController
{

    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\View\Factory|\Illuminate\Http\Response|\Illuminate\View\View
     */
    public function index()
    {
        return view('admin.user.index');
    }

    ...

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is very good practice and a good way to avoid duplication. The only thing you might consider doing differently is renaming `AdminController` to something such as `AdminBaseController` or `AdminCommonController` to help make it more obvious that it's not a directly referenced controller.

If your controller folder starts to get cluttered, the fact that a number of controllers extend this common base controller becomes a good place to start in breaking things down into sub folders.

Comment: Thanks James for your advice. It will definitely help me a lot.